# Reject suggested edit reason as 'Spam'

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, spam

When reviewing suggested edits, there isn't a way of marking the suggested edit specifically as being spam. It can be rejected as an invalid edit, but there then isn't any record of this user using edits as a spam mechanism. Same applies for using the custom reason.

I'd like to suggest that suggested edits have an explicit 'spam' or 'report' option to them so that existing spam monitoring can be applied to suggested edits.

Answer (score 13):

Use the vandalism rejection reason if an edit is editing spam into a post.

> [image]

Comment: Would it not be beneficial to track the two separately for the sake of monitoring spam trends?

Comment: @PhonicUK: Do you see a lot of actual spam in the suggested edit queue then?

Comment: @PhonicUK I'm with Martijn; I see so little posts requiring rejection as vandalism (barring audits) that I don't see this as being needed.

Comment: @PhonicUK AFAICT the only vandalism incl spam edits are review audits...  (low quality q/a are real spam sometimes)